# grails scaffolding broken

Tags: grails, scaffolding, scaffold

Grails scaffoldin does not work in my grails application.
When I go from the main page to the specific controller page it output something like this:

```
Error 500:
Servlet: default
URI: /myapp/myDomain/list
Exception Message: Tag [sortableColumn] is missing required attribute [title] or [titleKey] at /webTestDummyDomain/list:25
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: Tag [sortableColumn] is missing required attribute [title] or [titleKey] at /myDomain/list:25
Class: /myDomain/list
At Line: [25]
Code Snippet:
```

Code snippet empty. If I try to create a new app scaffold works perfectly.

Additional data:

```
Application Status

    * App version: 0.1
    * Grails version: 1.2.2
    * JVM version: 1.6.0_20
    * Controllers: 11
    * Domains: 10
    * Services: 19
    * Tag Libraries: 26

Installed Plugins

    * i18n - 1.2.2
    * filters - 1.2.2
    * logging - 1.2.2
    * core - 1.2.2
    * tomcat - 1.2.2
    * webtest - 2.0.4
    * functionalTest - 1.2.7
    * yui - 2.7.0.1
    * rest - 0.3
    * jquery - 1.4.2.1
    * bubbling - 2.1.2
    * urlMappings - 1.2.2
    * groovyPages - 1.2.2
    * servlets - 1.2.2
    * dataSource - 1.2.2
    * controllers - 1.2.2
    * codecs - 1.2.2
    * jqueryUi - 1.8-SNAPSHOT
    * grailsUi - 1.2-SNAPSHOT
    * domainClass - 1.2.2
    * mimeTypes - 1.2.2
    * scaffolding - 1.2.2
    * converters - 1.2.2
    * hibernate - 1.2.2
* validation - 1.2.2
* services - 1.2.2
```

Can you give me any pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what happened. I had a taglib without namespace redefinition and with a closure named "message". And that closure was running instead i18n function "message" so it didn't output nothing. And the tag generated by grails scaffolding named "sortable" it need a attribute that need the output of the i18n function.

For the next time I have to try to name my functions with names that doesn't appear in the grails reference.

Thanks @Steven for your answer though.

Comment: Or even better, use proper packaging and namespacing to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe something got renamed and the mapping between the controller and view is wacked.

Can you try creating a new domain class and then a new controller. Once you do that, try to go to the new controller page after you run-app.